# Can PEGjs take the "closing" character of a statement as input?

Tags: javascript, pegjs

I've been working on a PEGjs grammar. Most of it works, but I'm having trouble with one last thing. My parser takes input that looks like this: `First:[content];` and returns the type  (First or Second)  and each of the elements inside content ("c", "o"...). I also need it to be able to take `]` as input so it should be able to parse the following: `First:[co]nt];`.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can go about this? This is what I have so far:

```
prod = unit+
unit = u:(form / size)
form = key:(kind)  ":" value:(clas)  ";"  {return {type:key, value:value} }
clas = "[" v:(charact+) "]" { return {type:"class",value:v} }
kind = "First" / "Second"
charact = letters / symbols
symbols = "(" / ")" / "!" / "?"  /  "%"  / "{" /  "}" / "[" // "]"
letters = [A-Za-z]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to look for a `]` not followed by a semicolon, ie. `"]" (!";")`. In the example below, I also use `$()` to combine the `symbols` into a single string.

```
prod = unit+
unit = u:(form / size)
form = key:(kind)  ":" value:(clas)  ";"  {return {type:key, value:value} }
clas = "[" v:(charact+) "]" { return {type:"class",value:v} }
kind = "First" / "Second"
charact = letters / symbols
symbols = $("(" / ")" / "!" / "?"  /  "%"  / "{" /  "}" / "[" / "]" (!";"))
letters = [A-Za-z]
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! What exactly does $() does? Is it basically the same as a join?

Comment: Yep, same as string join.